# Hadoop Map/Reduce Job progress counters

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have a map/reduce job and I want to track the number of records processed in the map phase of the job. To do that, I am using Custom Counters, and incrementing them by 1, in my map phase. Also, I am monitoring these counters after every 30 seconds.

However, when I am checking the job counters progress using Job Client, I am looking at the number of records processed are not even with each periodic interval. Sometimes, there is no change and sometimes there is.

```
context.getCounter(ApplicationCounters.TOTAL_NUMRECORDS_PROCESSEDBY_MAP)
            .increment(1);
```

My hadoop cluster heartbeat interval is 15 seconds. Does not that means, I should get regular consistent updated.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your job has finished, using waitForCompletion is recommended. Querying the counter during runtime can end in strange results.

> The counters are globally aggregated by the framework at the end of
>   the job.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the job progress at run time, a kind of aggregation to happen at run time.